# QFileDialog.getSaveFileName allows illegal characters to be entered as a path Python3, PyQt5

Tags: pyqt5, qfiledialog

In my PyQt5 GUI I use a QFileDialog widget to allow the user to select a file path to save some data to. However, the QFileDialog allows special characters such as commas, &, @, #, etc., to be used in the path/file name. This will cause some obvious problems if I tried to access the file location containing invalid characters. I am looking for a way to prevent the user from entering these characters into the file path field in the first place. Is there a way to stop the QFileDialog widget from accepting these invalid characters BEFORE the QFileDialog widget closes? Is there a way to prevent those characters from appearing in the file path file path field inside the QFileDialog popup widget when the user types them? Please respond with Python code, NOT C++.

Comment: The characters `, & # @` aren't invalid in filenames on either Unix or Windows. Please provide a [mre] which shows how you are able to create a file using a path containing *genuine* invalid characters. You should also state which platform you are testing on.